# On simple extension on Q

Tags: field-theory

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}\right)$ is a simple extension on $\mathbb{Q}$. More precisely, show that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}\right)=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}\right)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ as $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$.

Now, $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}) \because \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}= \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}}$

$\therefore \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})$.

$\therefore \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})$.

$\therefore \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})$.

Comment: Please do use LaTeX to write mathematics in this, otherwise it is very hard to understand

Comment: @Novice : I have edited some parts of your post to indicate how to write in Latex. Please go through it and edit the rest.

Comment: Actually I can type everything in Latex. But it is a bit troublesome as I just jot down what I am thinking about the problem. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Done with the editing. Another method of doing this is to use some Linear Algebra technique by considering basis. But that method is not as clear cut as this.:)